# Google Purchases.subscriptions API - token for defer method

Tags: android, xamarin, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, subscription

I add subscriptions in my existing Android app.  I previously used product purchases in the app.I want to provide users who bought the product a free subscription for 1 year. I found this function in Google Api - [Purchases.subscriptions: defer](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions/defer). This is excellent, but one of the parameters this method -

```
 **token**  (string)    The token provided to the user's device when the subscription was purchased.
```

But the application does not have this data, the user has not yet purchased a subscription. I just want to postpone the payment date for this user for a year.

Do I need a first payment to get a token?

Then this method is not suitable for me. Any ideas?

Comment: Did the original user purchase the app during download (i.e. a non-free app) or did they In-App purchase a non-consumable sku for some feature unlock?

Comment: He made a purchase (non-consumable product)